# Header problems with use of convertAndSendToUser method in Spring WebSocket

Tags: spring-websocket

I'm trying to send a message directly to an user using `SimpMessageSendingOperations` or `SimpMessagingTemplate` but both doesn't work.

```
simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/user/" + userSessionId + "/queue/greetings", "Message One");

messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(userSessionId, "/queue/greetings", "Message Two");
```

I already inspected the internal classes to understand the problem and seems to be the headers.
For example, if I create a `StompHeaderAccessor` and specially add any `nativeHeaders` and also add SessionId header and send as the last parameter of `convertAndSendToUser` it works.

```
StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.create(StompCommand.SEND);
headerAccessor.setSessionId(purchaseReport.getSessionId());
headerAccessor.setNativeHeader("Any header", "Any header");

messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(purchaseReport.getSessionId(), "/queue/greetings", "Message Two", headerAccessor.toMap());
```

Because inside the `SimpMessagingTemplate` class there is a method called `processHeadersToSend` and if there is any Native headers it returns the same headers so in `AbstractMessageSendingTemplate` class the type of `headersToUse` variable changes to a HashMap and the behavior is different.

I also created a method annotated with `@SendToUser` to understand the idea and the same behavior happens:

```
@MessageMapping({ "/hello/{id}/websocket" })
@SendToUser(value = "/queue/greetings")
String generate(@DestinationVariable Integer id, @Payload Report report,
                  SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor) throws Exception {

messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(headerAccessor.getHeader("simpSessionId").toString(),
                "/queue/greetings", "This message doesn't work");


messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(headerAccessor.getHeader("simpSessionId").toString(),
                "/queue/greetings", "This one works because have native headers", headerAccessor.toMap());


return "This one send by annotation works too";
```

I'd like what I'm doing wrong or I really need to always instantiate a HeaderAccessor and add any native headers to work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand and solve my problem, I didn't pay attention to the JavaDoc description in `processHeadersToSend`.

The `convertAndSendToUser` accepts a `Map<String, Object>` parameter as the headers, but correct is send a `MessageHeaders` if I want to keep my own headers.

So I created a method:

```
    private MessageHeaders createHeaders(String sessionId) {
        SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = SimpMessageHeaderAccessor
                .create(SimpMessageType.MESSAGE);
        headerAccessor.setSessionId(sessionId);
        headerAccessor.setLeaveMutable(true);
        return headerAccessor.getMessageHeaders();

    }
```

And call `convertAndSendToUser` like this:

```
messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(purchaseReport.getSessionId(),
                    "/queue/greetings",
                    payload,
                    createHeaders(sessionId));
```

Thanks.

Comment: I can't stop wondering how unclear the Spring Websocket docs are. Headers field marked as @Nullable but in fact it is mandatory. Because no headers - no message sent. Your tip saved my day.